# Fibrations of manifolds with boundary - reference request

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, geometric-topology, manifolds-with-boundary, fibration

A smooth map $f\colon M\to B$ between **compact** manifolds is a *fibration* if it is surjective and submersive. I would like to use the same definition when $M$ and $B$ have boundary. Write
$$
\partial M = \partial_{\mathrm{vert}}M\cup \partial_{\mathrm{hor}}M
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\partial_{\mathrm{vert}}M=f^{-1}(\partial B),\quad \partial_{\mathrm{hor}}M=\overline{\partial M\setminus \partial_{\mathrm{vert}}M}.
$$
Is it true that $f|_{\partial_{\mathrm{hor}}M}\colon \partial_{\mathrm{hor}}M\to B$ is a fibration, too?

If yes, I would like to ask if it is a standard fact, or there is some reference where it is clearly stated. If no, is there a standard definition of fibrations between manifolds with boundary for which one has a decomposition like above?

Comment: Are you assuming $M$ is compact?  If not this definition is non-standard.  For example projecting $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a point removed to the first coordinate is a surjective submersion but is not a fibration in the usual sense of lifting homotopies.

Comment: Yes, I assume both $M$ and $B$ are compact. Thank you! I've edited by question.

Comment: There do exist standard definitions of fibrations. The statement in your first sentence is not one of those definitions, although that statement is a true theorem when the appropriate definition of fibration is used. So what you want is somewhat unclear. Are you asking for a generalization of that theorem to manifolds with boundary? Do you know any of the standard definitions of fibrations?

Comment: I admit that I was too fast. I should've used the following definition: $f: M\to B$ is a fibration if for any point $p\in B$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a diffeomorphism $g:U\times f^{-1}(p)\to f^{-1}(U)$ such that $f\circ g$ is the first projection. By Ehressmann lemma, for compact manifolds with boundary this is equivalent to $f$ being surjective and submersive. I think that if I assume that $f|_{\partial_{hor} M}$ is surjective and submersive, too, I will get that $f$ is a fibration. So, I am asking for a reference to an Ehresmann lemma for manifolds with boundary. I'm sorry.